# How do bounties work in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim and going on a rampage for fun. I was watching my bounty go up and go down and that sparked the question of how do bounties work? If you kill someone and someone sees you, how long does it take for the bounty to be permanent (Saying if you kill them and your bounty goes away) and how come when you kill someone when going on a rampage or having a high bounty, your bounty only decreases by 40 even when everyone is killed? Can someone tell me how bounties work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Bounty is separated by hold. I.e. in Whiterun you'll have a different bounty counter than in Markath.
2. Killing all witnesses of the crimes nullifies the bounty.

Either or both of those are responsible for your up and down bounty numbers.

Apart from that, you can only pay off the bonuty, go to jail, resist arrest and use your title (Thane) to nullify lesser crimes.

Comment: Bounty is separated by **region**; Whiterun hold is part of Whiterun region. However, Riverwood is also part of Whiterun region. If you commit a crime in whiterun you'll have a bounty in riverwood, and vice-versa

Comment: @Oak he said hold. That's the same thing. The hold is not a city, the city is the capital of a hold. The hold is a region.

Comment: +1, some more details at The Elder Scrolls Wiki: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty_%28Skyrim%29